# Rollup distribute TypeScript definitions for Javascript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

I've been asked to add TypeScript type definitions for exported modules  inside a JavaScript library built with Rollup.

I've written the `.d.ts` files along side and now I think I need to configure rollup (or some plugin) to take those definitions and bring them (eventually merged?) into the `dist` directory.

The library is organised as follows:

```sh
MyLib
|_/dist
| |_ index.js
| |_ index.js.map
|
|_/src
| |_/componentA
| | |_ index.js
| | |_ index.d.ts
| |
| |_/componentB # this is not exported, thus no use of TS.
| | |_ index.js
| |
| |_/componentC
|   |_ index.js
|   |_ index.d.ts  
|_ index.js
|_ package.json
|_ rollup.config.js
|
|_ etc...
```

I've searched for issues, read Rollup documentations and searched for issues in the Rollup repo but couldn't find anything helpful.

An example of file is

```
import * as React from 'react'

declare class Launcher extends React.Component<LauncherProps, any> {}

export interface LauncherProps {
  brandSvg: string;
  documentationUrl?: string;
  // ...
}

export default Launcher
```

---

The `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "MyLib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/index.es.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8",
    "npm": ">=5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "ci": "env CI=true yarn lint && yarn coverage",
    "coverage": "yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "dev:start-example": "cd ./example && npm run start",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js",
    "prepare": "yarn run build",
    "predeploy": "cd example && yarn install && yarn run build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=1 react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "fast-levenshtein": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1"
  }
  "peerDependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.18.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^2.4.1",
    "antd": "^3.18.2",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-docgen": "^3.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.1",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^2.0.4",
    "eslint": "5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "rollup": "^0.64.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.1.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^2.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-url": "^2.2.1"
  },
}
```

The Rollup configuration file, `rollup.config.js`, is as follows:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescrip2'

import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      external: ['path']
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss({
      modules: false
    }),
    url(),
    svgr(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      plugins: [ '@babel/external-helpers' ]
    }),
    builtins(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript() // <-- added later
  ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

1. As suggested by @darklightcode in the answer I've updated `package.json` adding:

```
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "dist/index.d.ts"
  },
```

and created the `tsconfig.json` file accordingly:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Running the build script still does nothing.

2. Using `rollup-plugin-typescript2` (configuration above) gives the following error:

```sh
[!] Error: Unknown object type "asyncfunction"
Error: Unknown object type "asyncfunction"
    at Object._object (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:218:17)
    at Object._function (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:319:14)
    at Object.dispatch (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
    at /home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object._object (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
    at Object.dispatch (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
    at /home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:260:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object._array (/home/fredmaggiowski/Development/mylib/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:259:20)
```

Comment: Please post `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. Is your library on `npmjs` ?

Comment: @darklightcode I've added the `package.json`, I've no `tsconfig.json`. No the library is not on `npmjs`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json`, use the following keys to point to your `.d.ts` files:

```
{
   ...
  "typings": "definitions/index", // change the path to your main .d.ts
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "definitions/index" // change the path to your main .d.ts
  }
  ...
}
```

PS: Below is a `tsconfig.json`, so you can make an idea on where `tsconfig.json` exports the definition files, and what `package.json` is pointing to. Paths can be changed as you wish.

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "declaration": true, 
    "declarationDir": "definitions",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

PSS: Make sure your typings won't create conflicts with other types, wrap them up under a namespace.

Comment: All right, I'm going to try it right now, just one question. You said to change the path to my `main .d.ts`. What should this main do? As of now I only have different .d.ts files relative to the modules, not a `main`.

Comment: As of `main .d.ts` i meant , some `index.d.ts`, sorry for that. here is an image with my [.d.ts folder structure](https://i.ibb.co/7GCMJQ6/dts.png), currently it has an `index.d.ts` in the root of the folder `definitions`. The files from the image are generated on-save by typescript while i'm writing code, the types i write are exported by typescript to `definitions` folder, so i can keep my code clean, and prevent certain conflicts such as including `.ts` files (which means `*.d.ts` files will be included also, it's a small mistake, but a common one).

Comment: I've updated `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` but nothing is happening.. I've tried to add the following plugin [rollup-plugin-typescript2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2) to the `rollup.config.js` but it returns different errors depending where I place the plugin

Comment: I have updated the `tsconfig.json` in my answer, give it a try. And about those errors, are those typescript errors ?

Comment: Since you're using react don't forget about ` "jsx": "react", ` in `tsconfig.json`, I've just added it now in the sample.

Comment: I've added the `jsx` bit and updated the question with the error that is thrown

Comment: There was on issue on rollup-plugin-typescript2 with that, checkout the option `objectHashIgnoreUnknownHack` on their [github page](https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Yeah, I missed it, now it doesn't crash but still no .d.ts file is in my dist directory :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194445/discussion-between-darklightcode-and-fredmaggiowski).